# Can we use EXEC() within a select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
/* Loop through tempTotal to update the result table */

SET @RowCount = 1
SELECT @MaxRows = COUNT(*) FROM #TempTotal
WHILE @RowCount <= @MaxRows
BEGIN

SELECT @RowCount = @RowCount + 1, @DeviceId = DeviceId, @SourceName = SourceName,  @hrs     = Hrs
FROM  #TempTotal
WHERE rownum = @RowCount

EXEC ('UPDATE #TempInputSourceRpt SET [' + @SourceName + '] = ' + @Hrs + 'WHERE DeviceId = ' + @DeviceId)

END
```

I want to convert the above logic to remove looping and improve performance

Something like this would be really efficient

```
SELECT EXEC('UPDATE #TempInputSourceRpt SET [' + SourceName + '] = ' + Hrs + 'WHERE     DeviceId = ' + DeviceId) FROM #TempTotal
```

but SQL does not allow to use EXEC within SELECT.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @SQL Varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'Use MyDatabase'

SELECT @SQL = SQL + 
             'UPDATE #TempInputSourceRpt SET [' + 
              SourceName + '] = ' + 
              Hrs + 
             'WHERE DeviceId = ' + DeviceId + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + ';' 
FROM #TempTotal

PRINT @SQL
--EXEC (@SQL)
```

Run it with the `EXEC` remarked out first to see if it's what you need, then you can unremark it to run it.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried this but apparently concatenation takes longer than looping. And then of course there is a size limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You can select FROM an exec...

Comment: oops -- i was thinking of INSERT from an exec.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually you can SELECT from an EXEC, via the OPENROWSET trick.  See Ward Pond's article http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2005/08/01/the-openrowset-trick-accessing-stored-procedure-output-in-a-select-statement.aspx

Comment: nice -- i was right on accident.  :-)  Actually, that's really cool -- thanks.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can use my example and convert it using OPENROWSET method. I think the idea works great with SP's but not so great with tables directly.

Comment: Re-reading your question -- not sure how to avoid looping this way.

Answer (score 0):

What version of sql-server?  If 2008, MERGE is a great new function that would make this operation a lot easier.